# I am new to sql and i am using mysql and i can't use copy a table and create a local temp table and global temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE #local temp table (  
User_id int,  
User_name varchar (50),  
User_address varchar (150)  
) ;
```

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INT, User_name VARCHAR (50), User_address VARCHAR (150) )'
>   at line 2

```
CREATE TABLE ##new global temp table (  
User_id int,  
User_name varchar (50),  
User_address varchar (150)
);
```

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INT, User_name VARCHAR (50), User_address VARCHAR (150) )'
>   at line 2

```
SELECT* INTO newtable FROM employee;
```

> ER_SP_UNDECLARED_VAR: Undeclared variable: newtable

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I'd say the opposite. OP _is_ using MySQL, but trying non-MySQL statements.

Comment: *"I am new to sql and i am using mysql"* Welcome your first lession you are not using MySQL syntax but SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax.. 
MySQL uses `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..` (MSSQL) syntax for creating temp tables.. `CREATE TABLE #<table_name>` is SQL Server syntax.. @mr3oh5

Comment: *" I'd say the opposite. OP is using MySQL, but trying non-MySQL statements."* anyhow yes @jarlh i meant syntax mixing with that (deleted) comment aswell, i will remove that comment and make a new one to make it more clear..

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a temporary table in MySQL, you would use:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE local  (  
    User_id int,  
    User_name varchar(50),  
    User_address varchar(150)  
) ;
```

The convention that temporary tables start with '#' is specific to SQL Server (and Sybase).  In most databases, you use the `temporary` keyword for this purpose.

To create another table from an existing table, you use `CRAETE TABLE AS`.  This is so much part of SQL, that the operation is sometimes referred to as CTAS.  Once again, SQL Server (and Sybase) uses the `INTO` syntax.  In many databases, `INTO` is used for variable assignment.